# "The buffer supplied to a function was too small" cryptographic exception with certificate signing

Tags: c#, .net, certificate

I am trying to sign the file with the certificate stored in the certificate storage. The certificate is stored in the Local Computer storage.

While calling of

```
signedCms.ComputeSignature(cmsSigner, false);
```

I get the next CryptographicException: "The buffer supplied to a function was too small"

---

**UPDATE**

Code example:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {            
            const string ENC_STR = "this is my message to encrypt цшер ÄÄÄ";
            var oid = new System.Security.Cryptography.Oid("sha256");
            X509Store store = new X509Store("MY", StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
            X509Certificate2Collection collection = (X509Certificate2Collection)store.Certificates;

            X509Certificate2Collection cers = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, args[0], false);

            if (cers.Count > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" {0} certificates are found", cers.Count);

                var cer = cers[0];
                Console.WriteLine("Certificate {0} is found", cer.Subject);
                byte[] dataToSign = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ENC_STR);
                System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.ContentInfo contentInfo = new System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.ContentInfo(dataToSign);
                System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.SignedCms signedCms = new System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.SignedCms(contentInfo, true);
                System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.CmsSigner cmsSigner = new System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.CmsSigner(cer);

                cmsSigner.IncludeOption = X509IncludeOption.None;
                cmsSigner.DigestAlgorithm = oid;

                try
                {
                    signedCms.ComputeSignature(cmsSigner, false);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                }

                //return the signed message
                byte[] signatureValue = signedCms.Encode();

                Console.WriteLine("Signature is: {0} ", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(signatureValue));
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No certificates found");
            }

            store.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe this information will be helpful:

- The certificate has "äåö" characters in the Common Name and
  Organisation
- The exception is not thrown if the hash algorithm is
  SHA1. For sha256 (and other) exception is thrown.
- If I port the
  specific part of code to the .net core or .net standard the exception
  is not thrown.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/7812

Comment: Could you provide the section of code that calls your function `SignData` and the declaration of the `byte` array you are passing into that function call? It is likely that you have declared it too small.

Comment: Does it happen for all kinds of data? Just some certificates? Just some digest algorithms? What's the failure callstack? I can't reproduce this.